# how do i select a specific element inside an elements with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy

class rlgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bot'

    start_urls = [
    'https://rocket-league.com/trading?filterItem=0&filterCertification=0&filterPaint=0&filterPlatform=1&filterSearchType=1&filterItemType=0&p=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = {}
        offers = response.xpath('//div[@class = "col-3-3"]')
        for offer in offers:
            for item in offer.xpath('//div[@class = "rlg-trade-display-container is--user"]/div[@class = "rlg-trade-display-items"]/div[@class = "col-1-2 rlg-trade-display-items-container"]/a'):
                data['name'] = item.xpath('//div/div[@position ="relative"]/h2').extarct()
                yield data
```

Here is what I did so far - it doesn't work well. It scrapes the url and not the h2 tag how do I do that when it's inside so many divs?

Comment: extarct() ??? Is this in your code?

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse though an element in scrapy you need to start your xpath with "." else you will be parsing through the response, this is the correct way of doing it.

```
def parse(self, response):

    offers = response.xpath('//div[@class = "col-3-3"]')
    for offer in offers:
        for item in offer.xpath('.//div[@class = "rlg-trade-display-container is--user"]/div[@class = "rlg-trade-display-items"]/div[@class = "col-1-2 rlg-trade-display-items-container"]/a'):
            data = {}
            data['name'] = item.xpath('.//h2/text()').extarct_first()
            yield data
```